# preloaded images get loaded again

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm preloading my images in `componentDidMount` like this:

```
photos.forEach(picture => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = picture.url;
});
```

however when I try to insert my images like this (in another component)

```
<img src={photos[0].url} ... />
```

it has to load the image again. In my network tab, I then have 2 identical requests for the same image from the same URL

[image: identical images]

with identical headers (except for the time ofc)

[image: image header (identical for both images)]

Comment: Is it not cached? You can check under the "size" column in the same Network tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable caching by the browser for the static resources like images/CSS/JS and other libraries such as jQuery etc which are not changed frequently. Try to add the cache-control response header for the static resources. These are the available values for **cache control** header.

```
Cache-Control: public 
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-transform
Cache-Control: private
Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
Cache-Control: max-age=<seconds>
Cache-Control: s-maxage=<seconds>
```

You can also add the **expires** response header when these static resources are served. Setting the value to a previous date will make the browser not to cache the response.

```
Expires: <http-date>
```

Comment: got it, the dev setup automatically prohibited caching so thats why I was having an issue

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour.
Why?
when you do img.src = picture.url; there will be a Request for the image will happen. 
next time you are assigning an src to img tag again --> img src={photos[0].url}
,so the next Request will be triggered. (should be from disk cache this time).

**let images = photos.map(picture => <img src={picture.src}/>);**
then render this images variable like
**ReactDOM.render(imgs, mountNode)**

Comment: Yes, requests are triggered, but if the headers are correct, the image is already cached in the browser, and will show instantly instead of downloading again. That's why yo can check if it was fetched from cache in the network tab.

Your answer is a bit misleading.