# HTML - Why is my preloaded resource loading again?

Tags: html, fonts, cross-domain, preload

### This is my example code:

```
  <body>
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2" as="font" />
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Roboto";
        src: url("/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
      }
      * {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      }
    </style>

    <section>
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </section>
  </body>
```

### What I expect:

`Roboto-Regular.woff2` gets downloaded once. The second access should take <5ms since it's reading from cache.

### What I actually see:

`Roboto-Regular.woff2` gets fully downloaded twice. The second access took as much time as the first one.

[image: Hard Refresh Waterfall]

The blue bar here is `Content Download`.

### What I have tried:

The solution suggested here: [preloaded images get loaded again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473008/preloaded-images-get-loaded-again). But I quickly realised my issue has nothing to do with cache. I have configured serverside cache-control, as seen here in the response header for the file:

[image: Response Header]

The previous waterfall screenshot is taken after a hard refresh (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd>); this one is taken after a soft refresh:

[image: Soft Refresh Waterfall]

This time both requests simply got their response from cache, which shows that cache has nothing to do with the whole situation.

## So what has gone wrong here?

### My environment:

Windows 10 Pro N 1909

Google Chrome 78.0.3904.108 x64

Comment: Why are you declaring the font face again?

Comment: I'm simply using Roboto as an example. In deployment I have custom font files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It turns out it's related to CORS.

I accidentally stumbled across the answer today when I noticed several new warnings in the console that weren't there before.

[image: New warnings]

These warnings basically described my issue exactly as they are. I did a quick Google search and landed here: [Preloading content with rel="preload"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#Cross-origin_fetches), which said:

> One interesting case where this applies, even if the fetch is not cross-origin, is font files. Because of various reasons, these have to be fetched using anonymous mode CORS.

As suggested, I simply threw in `crossorigin` to my preload declaration:

`<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2" as="font" crossorigin />`

And my preload worked.

[image: Preload Working]

---

### Also

If you are preloading a resource with MIME type of `fetch` such as `.json`, you also need to include the `crossorigin` attribute in your preload declaration for similar reasons (I assume) ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-as)).

[image: fetch requires crossorigin too]

Answer (score 4):

For the next one who arrives here:

If you have the same issue (double download of your asset) but you've already set the `crossorigin` property.

```
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2" as="font" crossorigin />
```

Are you really requesting an asset cross-origin?

**Try removing it!**

```
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Roboto-Regular.woff2" as="font" />
```

Comment: we need to add crossorigin to font files even if they are on the same origin, isn't it ? as mentioned in the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

When opening the developer tools, chrome disables the cache, what can cause a reload of resources. Remove the checkmark on the `disable cache` box in the menu bar mostly fix the issue.

Comment: disabling cache does not cause the browser to issue two requests for the same resource.

Comment: @VijayaraghavanPurush It absolut can happen in chrome. Often in combination mit js/lazy loading. I don't know why but it is a common issue and is reproducible.